# What's the syntax on this line of code?

Tags: printing

What's the syntax on this line of code (part of a script that create a html window and prints?)

```
function (write)

{var ctx=$(this)[offset]();

ctx[drawImage](this,ctx[left]-slidePos[left],ctx[top]-slidePos[top]);

});
```

Comment: In computer science, the term _syntax_ refers to the rules governing the composition of meaningful texts in a formal language. In this sense I don't understand your question. Do you want to know what the code does? In this case you are looking for the semantics of the code.

Comment: apologies-I have a syntax error on line 13, I'm, trying to pop open an html window print an html slide. Thankyou David.

Comment: First, which of the shown lines is line 13? Second, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377): You seem to ask us what's wrong with your solution, without giving any details on what problem you are trying to solve. Please edit your question and provide more details. Otherwise it's unlikely that you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This invokes the jQuery function and returns a jQuery object (referencing `this` in the current context):

```
$(this)
```

An object's properties (some of which may be functions) can be indexed on the object, so this is indexing a specific property:

```
$(this)[offset]
```

Turns out this property is a function, because it's invoked:

```
$(this)[offset]()
```

The returned result of that function is stored in a variable:

```
var ctx=$(this)[offset]()
```

That variable is presumably another object, which can also have its properties indexed:

```
ctx[drawImage]
```

And that indexed property can also be a function:

```
ctx[drawImage]()
```

That function takes three arguments:

```
ctx[drawImage](this,ctx[left]-slidePos[left],ctx[top]-slidePos[top])
```

The first argument is simply `this` in the current context.  The second argument is an arithmetic expression of another property on that object minus a property on another object:

```
ctx[left]-slidePos[left]
```

So is the third argument:

```
ctx[top]-slidePos[top]
```

These two lines together are encapsulated within a function:

```
function (write)
{
    // ...
}
```

Oddly enough, that function doesn't appear to use the `write` argument that it expects.